# Valgrind does not show line numbers

Tags: c, makefile, valgrind

I have added the -g option to the makefile like this:

```
CFLAGS=-Wall -g

all:
        cc hello.c -o hello
        cc badprog.c -o badprog
```

When I compile using make:

```
 cc hello.c -o hello
 cc badprog.c -o badprog
```

I dont see the `-g` option here.The result for `valgrind --track-origins=yes ./badprog` looks like:

```
 ==14412== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
 ==14412==    at 0x4E7D665: _itoa_word (_itoa.c:179)
 ==14412==    by 0x4E81B91: vfprintf (vfprintf.c:1654)
 ==14412==    by 0x4E880A8: printf (printf.c:34)
 ==14412==    by 0x400564: main (in /home/anr/Desktop/c programming/badprog)
 ==14412==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
 ==14412==    at 0x40052C: main (in /home/anr/Desktop/c programming/badprog)
```

Comment: This is a useless "makefile".  Why don't you just use a shell script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `CFLAGS` wasn't referenced in the compilation commands. Modify your Makefile into:

```
CFLAGS=-Wall -g

all:
        cc hello.c $(CFLAGS) -o hello
        cc badprog.c $(CFLAGS) -o badprog
```